# Monotouch - Usage of Activity Indicator View on Button TouchDown

Tags: ipad, view, android-activity, xamarin.ios, indicator

Does anyone know how to display an Activity Indicator View in a Alert View on a TouchDown event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a class that i created for this problem : https://gist.github.com/994791

You can use it like a normale UIAlertView.

Answer (score 1):

Cool Thanks, I actually came up with this. It's a different approach:

```
public class ActivityIndicator : IDisposable
{
    UIAlertView _alert;
    UIActivityIndicatorView _ai;

    public ActivityIndicator (String title)
    {
        _alert = new UIAlertView(title, String.Empty, null, null, null);
        _ai = new UIActivityIndicatorView();
        _ai.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(125,50,40,40);
        _ai.ActivityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge;
        _alert.AddSubview(_ai);
        _ai.StartAnimating();

        _alert.Show();
    }

    #region IDisposable implementation
    void IDisposable.Dispose ()
    {
        _alert.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```